# onclick show/hide function and addClass/removeClass on two separate navigations canceling itself out/not working

Tags: jquery

I have two navigations on the website (not the main navi) with each onclick displaying content underneath. The first content of each is also active, so to be displayed at page load, the button/link changes active class on click for the hover to stick.

I have searched and tried several things but with my very limit knowledge of JS/jQuery did not make any headway. My jQuery below (last try).

P.S. The jQuery works fine with one navigation, and I managed to get it to work with both, but they cancel each others content out (click on one hides all others). Haven't found a semi-workable solution for `addClass/removeClass` though.

**[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzkj8nwa/1/)**.

**jQuery :**

```
$("#nav1, #nav2 a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".toggle").hide(); //also tried $(".toggle,.toggle1") with the seperate navi content having classes toggle and toggle1
  var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
  $(toShow).show();
});

var selector = '.box';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
  $(selector).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

// tried this for active class but doesnt work

var selector = '.last-nav';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
  $(selector).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**EDIT:**

If I could bother some more.

The first part worked like a charm, the .closest('section') I found particularly illuminating, aswell as the id^= and id*= - yes im very new to js. :)
But I still have a problem with the second part. As is, when one clicks on one navigation, the active Class (example Button) also hides on the second navigation. I would like the buttons in the first navi to keep the active Class also after clicking a link in the second navi (so both have own active Classes assigned).

I tried with .closest('section') again but didn't work (tried it on all three rows and each row alone, worth a shot I guess).

I again tried like this (assigning diff classes to each)

```
var selector = '.nav-active';
$(selector).on('click', function(){
$(selector).removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});

var selector = '.nav-active2';
$(selector).on('click', function(){
$(selector).removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

For some reason it seems to work on the second navigation, but on the first (with buttons) it doesn't remove the active Class (although it does add it - hover effect sticks).

I hope the above is understandable, it was a long day.

Thankye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzkj8nwa/3/)**.

You should not use `$(".toggle")` selector else all the elements with this class will be affected, instead target just those who're inside the section if clicked anchor `a` using the following selector :

```
$(this).closest('section').find(".toggle").hide();
```

**NOTE :** To target the both `nav`'s you could use class or id selctors like :

```
$("[id^='nav'] a").click(function(e){
//Or
$(".row a").click(function(e){
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("[id^='nav'] a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $(this).closest('section').find(".toggle").hide();
  
  var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
  $(toShow).show();
});

var selector = '.box';
$(selector).on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('section').find(selector).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
   color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="row" id="nav1">                
    <ul class="list">  
      <li>
        <a href="#link1" class="box active">
          <p>BUTTON 1</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#link2" class="box">
          <p>BUTTON 2</p>
        </a>
      </li>            
    </ul>             
  </div>

  <div class="toggle" id="link1" style="display:block">                  
    <h2>Content 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle" id="link2" style="display:none">
    <h2>Content 2</h2>                
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="row" id="nav2">
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#link3" class="last-nav box active">Link 1</a></li>
    </ul>  
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="#link4" class="last-nav box">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="toggle" id="link3" style="display:block">   
    <h2>Content 3</h2>
  </div> 
  <div class="toggle" id="link4" style="display:none">
    <h2>Content 4</h2> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Zakaria thank you kindly for answering. I will take a look at your code tomorrow morning and will give feedback then, but looks promising, even at this hour (I understand it supperficially but really need to delve into it to grasp it). :)
Thank you again!

Comment: Hey @Zakaria (and anybody taking a look). Im still having issues with the second part of the script which adds/removes the class. I have update mz OP. Again, help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check my update @Samo, the code will work fine with the use of `closest()` and by adding the `.box` class to the section 2 anchors..

Comment: find(selector), of course. Again, thank you thank you @Zakaria!